# Create SQLite database in memory

Tags: php, database, sqlite, pdo, in-memory-database

Trying to learn a bit about PDO and is going through [this tutorial](http://www.phpro.org/tutorials/Introduction-to-PHP-PDO.html). It has the following snippet of code:

```
<?php

  try
  {
    $db = new PDO('sqlite::memory');
    echo "SQLite created in memory.";
  }
  catch(PDOException $e)
  {
    echo $e->getMessage();
  }
```

When I run this I get the following exception message:

> SQLSTATE[HY000] [14] unable to open database file

What does that mean? How can I get it to work? I am able to connect to a MySQL database and also a regular SQLite database file. So I know at least something is working...

I'm on Windows 7 64-bit with Apache 2.2.11 and PHP 5.3.0 (latest [WampServer](http://www.wampserver.com/) install). `phpinfo()` reports that I have pdo_sqlite with SQLite Library 3.6.15 enabled.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

You have to write

```
$db = new PDO('sqlite::memory:');
```

the trailing `:` is missing.

---

> The PDO_SQLITE Data Source Name (DSN) is composed of the following elements:
>
> The DSN prefix is **sqlite:**.
>
> - To access a database on disk, append the absolute path to the DSN prefix.
> - To create a database in memory, append **:memory:** to the DSN prefix.

[Documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-sqlite.connection.php)

Comment: Un-believable... haha. Thanks :D

Comment: Does this DB recreated each time the script executed ? or it will be stored in memory ?

Answer (score 2):

Not sure @ win permissions, but on *nix, SQLite needs write permision to the dir confining database files for temp files.